# Two quick questions about convergence (in the context of pointwise vs. uniform convergence)

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I found this example online:

> Let $\{f_{n}\}$
>     be the sequence of functions on $(0,\infty)$
>     defined by $f_{n}(x)=\frac{nx}{1+n^{2}x^{2}}$
>    .This function converges pointwise to zero. 
>   Indeed, $(1+n^{2}x^{2})\sim n^{2}x^{2}$
>     as $n$
>     gets larger. 
>   So, $\underset{n\rightarrow\infty}{\lim}f_{n}(x)=\underset{n\rightarrow\infty}{\lim}f_{n}(x)=\frac{nx}{n^{2}x^{2}}.=\frac{1}{x}\underset{n\rightarrow\infty}{\lim}\frac{1}{n}=0.$
>
> But for any $\epsilon<1/2$
>    , we have
>
> $|f_{n}(\frac{1}{n})-f(\frac{1}{n})|=\frac{1}{2}-0>\epsilon$
>    .
>
> Hence$ \{f_{n}\}$
>     is not uniformly convergent.

1. By the definition of pointwise convergence: $f_n(x)\rightarrow f(x)$ for all $x\in X$. But this does not seem to happen when $x=\frac{1}{n}$. So how can ${f_n}$ converge pointwise to zero for all $x\in (0,\infty)$ if $f_{n}(\frac{1}{n})=\frac{1}{2}$?
2. Is it correct to think like this: If $ \{f_{n}\}$ was uniformly convergent, then if someone gave me an $\epsilon<1/2$, I should be able to find and $n\geq N$ so that  $|f_{n}(x)-f(x)|$ became smaller than $1/2$ for any $x \in (0,\infty)$, but this doesn't hold for *any* $x$ because we saw that $|f_{n}(\frac{1}{n})-f(\frac{1}{n})|=\frac{1}{2}-0>\epsilon$, so ${f_n(x)}$ cannot be uniformly convergent.

Comment: pointwise means you fix an $x$.

Comment: @Yimin What do you man by "fix an x"? What happens if i fix $x=1/n$?

Comment: $1/n$ is changing...

Comment: @Yimin Ohh, of course. Thanks! :)

Comment: See also https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/588976/to-prove-that-f-nx-fracnx1n2x2-does-not-uniformly-converge-to-fx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pointwise convergence $f_n(x)\underset{n\to\infty}{\to}{f(x)}$ is convergence by $n$  at every (but fixed) argument $x$.