# To prove that $f_n(x) = \frac{nx}{1+n^2x^2}$ does not uniformly converge to $f(x) = 0$ on $[0,1]$

Tags: uniform-convergence

**My Approach**. To prove the given statement it is sufficient to show that $$\exists \epsilon > 0, \exists x \in [0,1], \forall N \in \mathbb{N}, \exists n > N $$
$$ \Rightarrow | f_n(x) - f(x)| > \epsilon$$

Let $\epsilon = \frac{1}{10}, x = \frac{1}{n}, n =N+1$. Hence $| f_n(x) - f(x)| = \frac{1}{2} > \epsilon = \frac{1}{10}$. Hence, we have shown for every $N \in \mathbb{N}$, how to choose $n$ such that $| f_n(x) - f(x)| > \epsilon$. Thus, $f_n(x)$ does not converge uniformly on $[0,1]$.

Is there any logical flaw or wrong steps in my proof. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: This is fine. You've found the maximum point of $|f_n-f|$, as you should have.

Comment: And those points give the same maximum and converge to 0.

Comment: A [related problem](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/370023/how-to-prove-a-sequence-of-a-function-converges-uniformly/370071#370071).

Comment: @ncmathsadist: Say what?

Comment: Strange how this exact question due in my advanced calculus class tomorrow morning... coincidence?

Answer (score 5):

Can you the other characterization of uniform continuity: $(f_n) \to f $ uniformly on $S$ iff

$$ \lim [ \sup\{ |f(x) - f_n(x) : x \in S \} ] = 0 \; \; (proof?)$$

Your problem then is application of this problem. In fact, if $f = 0$, then

$$ |f_n - f | = f_n = \frac{nx}{1 + n^2x^2 } $$

Now,notice

$$ f_n' = \frac{n(1 + n^2x^2) - nx(2xn^2)}{(1 + n^2x^2)^2}$$

and

$$ f'_n(x) = 0 \iff x = \frac{1}{n}, \frac{-1}{n} $$

Hence

$$ f_n(  \frac{1}{n} ) = \frac{1}{2} \; \; \text{check this!} $$

$$ \therefore \lim \sup|f_n - f|  = \frac{1}{2} \neq 0$$

$$ \therefore f_n \; \; \text{does not converge uniformly to} \; \; f $$

Comment: Should one check the second (negative) x? Why didn't you do this?

Comment: @Bartłomiej Szałach the answerer didn't check that the second derivative is negative because we are already certain that $f_n$ cannot have a local minima at $x = \frac {1} {n},$ for otherwise $f_n$ will have a global minima at $x = \frac {1} {n},$ (Why?) which cannot be true because $f_n \left (\frac {1} {n} \right ) = \frac {1} {2} \gt 0 = f_n (0).$

Comment: That is how people here knew to take $x_n = \frac{1}{n}$ ?

Answer (score 1):

I actually have a question that how would test the convergence if the given function is a series instead of a sequence with n varying from 1 to infinity for any value of x.

Answer (score 0):

Look at $f(x)$ at $x = 1/(n\sqrt{3}).$

Comment: So what is wrong if I consider $x = \frac{1}{n}$.

Comment: That works too.

Answer (score 0):

To phrase things in a different language, what you (correctly) proved is that 
$$
\|f_n-f\|_\infty\geq\frac12
$$
for all $n$, where $\|\cdot\|_\infty$ is the $\sup$-norm (it is actually an equality, but that is not important for your proof).