# Uniform convergence of $\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{nx}{1 + n^2x^2} \text{ where } 0 \le x \le 1$

Tags: sequences-and-series, uniform-convergence, sequence-of-function

Prepering to second exam in Calculus 2,

and I remember this question from the first exam that I fell on:

> Let $f_n(x)$ be the function sequence $\{\frac{nx}{1 + n^2x^2}\}_{n=1}^\infty$
>
> Let $f(x)$ be the limit function such that $\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{nx}{1 + n^2x^2}$ convergences to.
>
> Does $f_n(x)$ convergents uniformly to $f(x)$?

As for the answers, the answer is ***no***.

Can you please explain me why?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is the pointwise limit? What is $f_n(1/n)$?

Comment: @DavidMitra The pointwise limit is $0$ (and this is the reason I though it convergents uniformly). $f_n(1/n)$ seems to be 1. Well, I've got the point.

Comment: Yes, the pointwise limit is $0$ on all of $\Bbb R$. $f_n(1/n)$ is  $1/2$. Now, if $(f_n)$ converged uniformly, there would be an $N$ so that for all $n\ge N$ and *all* $x$, we would have $|f_n(x)|<1/2$. Presents a quandry, no?

Comment: See also: [To prove that $f_n(x) = \frac{nx}{1+n^2x^2}$ does not uniformly converge to $f(x) = 0$ on $[0,1]$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/588976)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you investigate the $$c_n=\max\mid f_n(x)-f(x)\mid=\max\limits_{x\in[0,1]}\mid \frac{nx}{1+n^2x^2}\mid$$ then you find that it takes its maximum at $x=\frac{1}{n}$ so $$c_n=\frac{n.\frac{1}{n}}{1+n^2\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)^2}=\frac{1}{2} $$which means that $f_n(x)$ converges nonuniformly.

Comment: How do you conclude that "its maximum at $x=\frac{1}{n}$"?