# Showing that $f_n(x) = \frac{nx}{1+n^2x^2}$ does not converge uniformly

Tags: real-analysis, uniform-convergence, sequence-of-function

I am trying to show that $f_n(x) = \frac{nx}{1+n^2x^2}$ where $x\in \mathbb{R}$ does not converge uniformly.

I have made an attempt and would like to make sure that I am going about it in the right way (i.e. if my thought process is correct or I am missing something).

First note that $f_n(x) \rightarrow 0$ pointwise and so if it converges uniformly it should converge to $f(x) = 0$ as well. To show this is not the case, note that $f_n(\frac{1}{n}) = 1/2$.

Hence, given $\epsilon = \frac{1}{3}$ for all $N\in \mathbb{N}$ we can find $n\geq N$ and $x\in \mathbb{R}$ where $|f_n(x)-f(x)|\geq \epsilon$, indeed we can just take $n = N$ and $x = \frac{1}{n} \in \mathbb{R}$ and $|f_n(x)-f(x)| = |f_n(\frac{1}{n})| = \frac{1}{2}>\frac{1}{3} = \epsilon$.

This shows that $(f_n)$ does not converge uniformly.

Comment: $f_n\to 2/x$ pointwise...

Comment: I have edited the question, thanks!

Comment: Now it's ok. And your proof is correct.

Comment: Just a question, am I right in saying that I only really need to find an $n\geq N$ OR an $x\in \mathbb{R}$ that leads to a $|f_n(x)-f(x)|>\epsilon$?

Comment: @Dman Simply note that $\sup_{x\in \mathbb{R}}f_n(x)=\frac12 \ne 0$.

Comment: @Dr.MV  I did notice this, however I wanted to give it a go with the $\epsilon$-definition

Comment: You found an $\epsilon>0$, such that for all $N$ there exists an $n>N$ and an $x\in \mathbb{R}$, such that $|f_n(x)-f(x)| \ge \epsilon$

Comment: @Dr.MV but would it suffice to show there exists $n$ or an $x$ (not an $n$ AND an $x$)? For some other example say, not this one.

Comment: No, not existence of such $n$. You need to show that given any $n$ you can find some $x$ such that your function varies from its pointwise limit by at least $\epsilon$ when evaluated at $x$.

Comment: @Zestylemonzi There exists an $\epsilon>0$, such that for all $N>0$ there exists an $n>N$ and an $x\in \mathbb{R}$ with $|f_n(x)-f(x)|\ge \epsilon$.  That is, for each $N>0$ we only need one $n>N$ to negate UC.

Comment: @Dr. MV Yup I agree. We're talking about different '$n$'s - I'm saying that you can not just show that there exists some $n \in \mathbb{N}$ and some $x$ such that $|f_n(x) - f(x)| > \epsilon$.

Comment: See also https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/588976/to-prove-that-f-nx-fracnx1n2x2-does-not-uniformly-converge-to-fx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The negation of uniform convergence on a set $A$ is, there exists a number $\epsilon>0$, such that for all $N$, there exists a number $n>N$ and an $x\in A$ with $|f_n(x)-f(x)|\ge \epsilon$.

If one finds a number $\epsilon>0$ such that for all $N$, there exists an $x\in A$ with $|f_n(x)-f(x)|\ge \epsilon$ for all $n>N$, then certainly this more than suffices as proof of uniform convergence on $A$.

Comment: Oh yes I forgot that there is actually an 'implies' in the definition and the negation of $X\Rightarrow Y$ is $S$ and not $Y$. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @Dman You're welcome.  My pleasure.  -Mark