# Uniform continuity of a sequence of functions of type $f_n(x)=f(nx)$

Tags: real-analysis, uniform-convergence

I asked this question before but I did not get a clear explanation for my problem with this question:

> Define the function $f(x)=\frac{2x}{1+x^2}$ and let $f_n(x)=f(nx)$.
>
> a) Show $f_n$ converges to 0 uniformly on $[1,\infty)$.
> b) Show $f_n$ converges to 0 on $[0,1]$? is it uniform convergence.

for part a, I did the calculations and I came to $|f_n(x)|<\frac{1}{2}$ so there is no $n$ here to be restricted such that I can construct an epsilon from? why would I conclude part "a" is correct with that inequality.
for part b, I ended up with $lim sup [|f_n(x)-f(x)|]=\frac{1}{2}\neq 0 $ so in interval of part "b", I must say the sequence of functions is not uniformly convergent. right?

Comment: I have taken the liberty to modify your title into something more attractive...

Comment: You should cite your previous identical question  : https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3606786. More generally it is not good acting to repost - only some hours later - the same question. Imagine everybody does that : this site would become a mess...

Answer (score 0):

For a) show that $\frac  {2t} {1+t^{2}}$ is decreasing function on $[1,\infty)$ (by showing that the derivative is negative). Hence the maximum  value of $f_n(x)$ is $f_n(1)=\frac {2n} {1+n^{2}}$ which tends to $0$ as $ n \to \infty$.

For b) use the fact that $\sup |f_n(x)| \geq |f_n(\frac  1 n)|=1$ so the convergence is not uniform on $[0,1]$.